# want the position of char in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want the character after the number 9 in a string but not getting the correct output.

```
declare @Col1 varchar(30)='39-0-9-6-17'

select SUBSTRING(@Col1, CHARINDEX('9', @Col1), (CHARINDEX('-', @Col1) + CHARINDEX('-', @Col1))-1)

select SUBSTRING(@Col1, CHARINDEX('9', CHARINDEX('9', @Col1, 1) ), (CHARINDEX('-', @Col1) + CHARINDEX('-', @Col1))-1)
```

Comment: This is going to be tricky, because (in theory) the `9` could be at the start, middle, or end of the string.  In addition, there could be more than one 9 value.  Please edit your question and cover these edge cases for us.

Comment: There are two `9`s in your string. Please be specific about which one you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a regular format here? I'm guessing not.

Comment: i want just the position of 9 not 39 and 9 can occur only once in this string.

Comment: Also, I guess you want the number following occurence of 9. Another question: should it be standalone, like `-9-` or can it be `-98-` or `-89-` etc.

Comment: it should be stand alone

Comment: Is this valid declare @Col1 varchar(30)='9-17' ?

Comment: You want "the character after 9", meaning only one? So you need index of nine + 1 character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "9" always appears as "-9-" with something after it, and not the first element in the list, then this would work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Col1, PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3, CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3) - (PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3));
```

I would imagine you would need to handle edge cases though?

You could also use this, to shorten the logic slightly:

```
DECLARE @partial INT = PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3;
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Col1, @partial, CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, @partial) - @partial);
```

To handle cases where the string starts "9-" then this works:

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(30)='9-10-11';
DECLARE @partial INT = PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3;
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(@Col1, 2) = '9-' THEN SUBSTRING(@Col1, 3, CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, 3) - 3)
ELSE SUBSTRING(@Col1, @partial, CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, @partial) - @partial) END;
```

One last edge case, where the number after the -9- is the final number, so doesn't have a "-" after it:

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(30)='19-5-99-9-17';
DECLARE @partial INT = PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3;
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(@Col1, 2) = '9-' THEN SUBSTRING(@Col1, 3, CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, 3) - 3)
ELSE SUBSTRING(@Col1, @partial, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, @partial) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, @partial) - @partial
ELSE LEN(@Col1) - @partial + 1 END) END;
```

Right, this is my final, FINAL edit, this is to handle the last edge case, where there are two numbers, and the first is the 9, so "9-1" for example:

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(30)='5888-39-9';
DECLARE @partial INT = PATINDEX('%-9-%', @col1) + 3;
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(@Col1, 2) = '-9' THEN NULL
        WHEN LEFT(@Col1, 2) = '9-' THEN SUBSTRING(@Col1, 3, 
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, 3) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, 3) - 3
                ELSE LEN(@Col1) - 2
            END)
        ELSE SUBSTRING(@Col1, @partial, 
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, @partial) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-', @Col1, @partial) - @partial
                ELSE LEN(@Col1) - @partial + 1 
            END) 
    END;
```

Comment: what is the string is -> declare @Col1 varchar(30)='9-17'

Comment: an edge case ;P

Comment: I work good but not getting error when declare @Col1 varchar(30)='19-5-99-9-17'

Comment: Yes, I added a fix for this

Comment: It work good but not getting error when declare @Col1 varchar(30)='19-5-99-9-17'

Comment: It is not working when given DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(30)='5888-39-9';

Comment: Well that's easy to fix, just added `WHEN RIGHT(@Col1, 2) = '-9' THEN NULL` to the `CASE` statement, so it will return a `NULL` if there is nothing after the "9".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select @Col1,
       SUBSTRING(@Col1,
           CHARINDEX('-9-', @Col1) + 3, 
           charindex('-', @Col1, CHARINDEX('-9-', @Col1) + 3) - CHARINDEX('-9-', @Col1) - 3
       )
```

It will return next number after standalone 9. For example:

```
'39-0-9-6-17' -> 6
'39-0-9-67-17' -> 67
'39-0-9-678-17' -> 678
```

To cover case, when `9` is at the beginning, the query complicates a little:

```
select Col1, SUBSTRING(Col1, CHARINDEX([Nine], Col1) + len([Nine]), 
    charindex('-', Col1, CHARINDEX([Nine], Col1) + len([Nine])) - 
    CHARINDEX([Nine], @Col1) - len([Nine]))
from (
    select @Col1 [Col1], case when @Col1 like '9[-]%' then '9-' else '-9-' end [Nine]
) a
```

It will resolve also case like:

```
'9-17-5-23' -> 17
etc.
```

Comment: for this declare @Col1 varchar(30)='9-17'  ?

Comment: @PawanKumar Modified query :)